# Decrease size of UITextView to reveal UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextview, uianimation

I have a text view in my app that has a done button beside it to resign the keyboard. Basically, rather than having the done button permanently beside the text view, I would like the text view to decrease in width when tapped, and then a done button would appear in the space. Then when the user taps the screen or the done button, the button disappears and the text view increases to it's normal size again.

I have already implemented the code for making the button appear when the user starts typing but I would like to change this so that it appears when they tap the text view and I also need help with adding the animation to shrink the text view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement your textview's delegate method `textViewShouldBeginEditing:`. Then in that method, do something like this:

```
button.alpha = 0.0f;
button.hidden = NO;
[UIView animationWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
    NSInteger padding = 5;
    CGRect textViewFrame = textView.frame;
    textViewFrame.width -= CGRectGetWidth(button.frame) - padding;

    // Edit
    textView.frame = textViewFrame;

    // and just to fade the button in as the text field shrinks
    button.alpha = 1.0;
}];
```

And I would do the opposite when you click the button to return the text field to the correct width

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm doing this in Swift and I was wondering what the equivalent of `textViewFrame.width -= CGRectGetWidth(self.notesDone.frame)` is in Swift? At the moment I am getting an error - Cannot invoke '-=' with an argument list of type '(CGFloat, CGFloat)'

Comment: I'm not familiar with Swift, but have you tried the equivalent `textViewFrame.width = textViewFrame.width - self.notesDone.frame.size.width` or does that just result in the same error?

Comment: Ah, I see. That gives me the error: 'Cannot assign to 'width' in textViewFrame'

Comment: Oh woops. I mean `textViewFrame.size.width`. I also edited my answer, noticed I forgot to set the textview's frame back to the new frame. Not sure if it matters, just didn't want to add confusion

Comment: That fixes the errors. It doesn't seem to do anything when run however. I have set the delegate for the UITextView to self and I returned true for `textViewShouldBeginEditing`. Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah that's right. Did you tell your class to implement the delegate? `@interface YourClassName : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>`? If you did, set a breakpoint in `textViewShouldBeginEditing` and see if it's even being called

Comment: I added a println to `textViewShouldBeginEditing` and it is indeed being called.

Comment: Update your question with all the related code. If I can't figure out an answer for you from that, it'll help others viewing this question to help you

Comment: Got it! Had to add `self.notesField.frame.size.width = textViewFrame.size.width`. Thanks for your help.